# Area of square with vertices: $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

If I know that:$$\int_C-ydx+xdy=\boxed{x_1y_2-x_2y_1}$$

So, why the area of square with vertices: $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),(x_4,y_4)$
is

> $\frac{1}{2}[(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)+(x_2y_3-x_3y_2)+(x_3y_4-x_4y_3)+(x_4y_1-x_1y_4)]$

Comment: Where come from your loop integral?

Comment: @EmilioNovati It is a line so it should be $\int_C$ and not $\oint_C$ you are right

Comment: Is $y_5$ a typo ?

Comment: I don't see $y_5$ here

Comment: @Nehorai You don´t see it, because muaddib has made an edit. Therefore is it right now ?

Comment: yes, it is correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you evaluate that line integral over all four edges, you get the expression at the bottom, but without the factor of $1/2$.

On the other hand, Green's theorem tells you that
$$
\int_{\partial R} P dx + Q dy = \int_R \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P} {\partial y} dA
$$

(I might have a sign error here); in your case, that tells you your line integral is the same as the integral of the constant $2$ over the area enclosed by the edges, giving twice the area. Hence *half* the line integral gives the area.

Comment: you mean that $$
\int_{\partial R} P dx + Q dy = \iint_R \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P} {\partial y} dA
$$ 
?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It is common practice to use the domain and differential of the integral to specify the "number" of integrals to use. Basically, $\int\int_RfdA=\int_RfdA$, but the second prevents the issue of having to fill the page with integrals and still communicates that it is an area integral instead of a path.